# Prove that dual norm is also a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

Recall the definition of a dual norm is

$$
{\|x \|}_* = {\max}_{\|z \|\leq 1} z^Tx 
$$

Positivity:
 if $x=0$, then it's obvious that $
{\|x\|}_*  $ is also $0$.  $$
{\|x\|}_* = \max_{\|z \|\leq 1} \sum z_ix_i \leq \max_{\|z \|\leq 1} \sum 
 |z_ix_i|$$

I'm stuck here and I don't how to show this greater zero.

Also have no idea on how to prove scaling, triangle inequality.

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is clear that $\|0\|_* = 0$.

If $x \neq 0$ then $\|x\| \neq 0$
and taking $z={x \over \|x\|}$, we have  $\|x\|_* \ge {\|x\|_2^2 \over \|x\|} >0$. In particular, if $\|x\|_* = 0$ we must have $x=0$.

Note that $\|x\|_* = \max_{\|z\| \le 1} |z^T x|$ and so
$\|tx\|_* = \max_{\|z\| \le 1} |z^T tx|= \max_{\|z\| \le 1} |t||z^T x|= |t| \max_{\|z\| \le 1} |z^T x| = |t| \|x\|_*$

Note that the functions $x \mapsto |z^T x|$ are convex, hence $x \mapsto \|x\|_*$ is convex.

By noting that $x+y = 2( {x +y \over 2})$, we can combine the last two facts
to show the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just have a question on the second part. How do I know that the dual norm equals to the absolute value of itself ?

Comment: You can always, if necessary, choose $-z$ instead of $z$ so that $z^T x \ge 0$. If you go to the complex world, you will need to use $|\cdot|$ anyway.

Comment: can you write that out explicitly ? I still don't see how z' * x >=0 when it is -z

Comment: @DataBall: I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but since $z_i x_i \le |z_i x_i|$ the last inequality in the question is immediate.